# ondeviceready and backbutton are not working in phonegap android?

Tags: android, cordova

```
    document.addEventListener("ondeviceready", function(){ alert("123");},true);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){ alert("123");},true);
```

//      I also used function separately but not worked
  //      I am using the correct cordova library
   //     I kept this code in external js file then also its not worked. 
  //      I also called it before including any other js file into the HTML
  //      same thing also happening for 'backbutton' event

```
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css.css" />
        <title>Since your car is manufactured before 2000</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
         alert("Back button pressed");
        },true);
    </script>
      </head>

    <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is called *deviceready*, not *ondeviceready*.

Also, you need the register the *backbutton* event **after** the *deviceready*-event has fired, otherwise, it will not work.

Modified example from the Cordova docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
    }

    function onBackButton(){
      // your code here
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```